# Trying to Calculate a percentage in Python sqlite3 based on values in a table

Tags: python, math, sqlite, sql-update, percentage

I am trying to create a percentage based on two factors (for a coin counting program) where I have to create an accuracy of how well people count the coins. This is calculated by getting the total number of bags of coins they have counted, and the total number of bags they have counted CORRECTLY, as a percentage of their total.

In my program, if volunteers enter the right weight of the coin bag for that specific coin, +1 gets added to the `bags_correct` column AND `total_bags` column. If the weight is wrong, +1 gets added to the `bags_incorrect` column as well as, again, the `total_bags` column.

I would then use this     `c.execute("UPDATE volunteers SET bags_correct = bags_correct + 1, total_bags = total_bags + 1, total_bags_value = total_bags_value + (?), percentage = (bags_correct / total_bags)*100 WHERE name = (?)", (100, name))`           to try and calculate a percentage (accuracy) but I get weird values such as '0' or '400', it needs to be a percentage i.e 0% to 100%, but I am having trouble doing so.

I have tried changing `real` to `integer` but the same thing occurred

Am I calculating it wrong in any way?

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("volunteers.db")

c = conn.cursor()


c.execute("""CREATE TABLE volunteers (
           name text,
           bags_correct integer,
           bags_incorrect integer,
           total_bags integer,
           total_bags_value integer,
           percentage real
           )""")





####This is when NEW volunteers add their first bag of coins when they counted it CORRECTLY without weight error.

c.execute("INSERT INTO volunteers VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (name, 1, 0, 
1, 100, 100))
conn.commit()


HOWEVER



####This is when NEW volunteers add their first bag of coins BUT it is INCORRECT

c.execute("INSERT INTO volunteers VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (name, 0, 1, 
1, 100, 0))
conn.commit()



####This is when NON-NEW volunteers add their bag of coins if it's CORRECT, hence the UPDATE.

c.execute("UPDATE volunteers SET bags_correct = bags_correct + 1, total_bags = total_bags + 1, total_bags_value = total_bags_value + (?), percentage = (bags_correct / total_bags)*100 WHERE name = (?)", (100, name))
conn.commit()



####This is when NON-NEW volunteers add their bag of coins but it's INCORRECT.

c.execute("UPDATE volunteers SET bags_incorrect = bags_incorrect + 1, total_bags = total_bags + 1, total_bags_value = total_bags_value + (?), percentage = (bags_correct / total_bags)*100 WHERE name = (?)", (100, name))
conn.commit()
```

NOTE: total_bag_value is in in pence.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your requirements accurately, but there are two things that i see incorrect with the update queries.

1. You are trying to update a column and use the same column in calculating a value for another column in same SQL statement. This is incorrect. In your first update statement for e.g. you increment `bags_correct` and `total_bags` by `1` and then do a `percentage = (bags_correct / total_bags) * 100`. Your bags will update correctly here but your percentage would be calculated on the previous values of the bags since the update actually does not apply to the db till you commit a transaction. You should instead be doing `percentage = (bags_correct + 1/ total_bags + 1) * 100`.
2. The second problem is that all the columns for bags are integer while you want to do a float division. The percentage you are calculating is doing an integer division and therefore whenever `bags_correct` is less than `total_bags`, your division automatically gets calculated as 0. What you need to do instead is that you need to cast the columns into float (or at least the numerator which would automatically force a float division). Something like `percentage = (CAST(bags_correct AS FLOAT) / CAST(total_bags AS FLOAT)) * 100`. If you want to store percentage as an `INT`, you can convert the result back to an integer if you want.

I hope this helps.